# setTimeout function is running infinitely

Tags: javascript, html

I read that setTimeout function only runs once and setInterval function runs infinitely. But in this code of digital clock which I picked from w3schools setTimeout is also running infinitely. Is it something to do with the onload method?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function startTime() {
            var today = new Date();
            var h = today.getHours();
            var m = today.getMinutes();
            var s = today.getSeconds();
            m = checkTime(m);
            s = checkTime(s);
            document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
                h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
            var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
        }

        function checkTime(i) {
            if (i < 10) {
                i = "0" + i
            }; // add zero in front of numbers < 10
            return i;
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">
    <div id="txt"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The startTime() function contains a call to setTimeout, and that setTimeout calls startTime(), so it runs infinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This version of `setInterval` is running infinitely because the `startTime` function is a **recursive function**. A recursive function is a function that calls **itself** during its execution, which, most of the time, means that the function runs infinitely.

See here:

```js
function startTime() {
  // Code...
  var t = setTimeOut(startTime, 500);
}
```

The `setTimeOut` is calling the `startTime` function, which in turn is calling the `setTimeOut` function... and it just keeps on going.

Answer (score 1):

This is a textbook case of recursion - `setTimeout()` calls `startTime()`, which calls `setTimeout()`...which in turn calls `startTime()` again.

You'll need to break that loop. Simply put, you cannot call `startTime()` from within `startTime()` without some path through the function that **doesn't** call `startTime()`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
      const myTimeout = setTimeout(startTime, 1000);

      function startTime() {
        const date = new Date();
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        setTimeout(function() {
          startTime()
        }, 1000);
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).